# Installing gcloud after GoogleAppEngineLauncher webapp2 import not found

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gcloud-python, google-cloud-python

I've been running GoogleAppEngineLauncher for a couple days, without incident.

This morning I installed the gcloud package from Google.

The issue is that now, regardless of where I run my AppEngine project from (GoogleAppEngineLauncher or using dev_appserver.py) it immediately 500's and the log is:

```
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/runtime/wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
    obj = __import__(path[0])
  File "/Users/roger/python/app.myapp/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    import webapp2
ImportError: No module named webapp2
```

I'm not entirely sure what happened to it, but webapp2 is clearly an important module for the application! It was working seamlessly previous to installing gcloud.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem yesterday and although I could not find why it was happening, I did manage to fix the problem.

I assume you did something similar to me where I installed gcloud using:
"pip install --user gcloud" and got a ton of libraries installed into my site-packages directory.  (I am using Mac OS X 10.11)  What I found is that although I do a pip uninstall gcloud, a bunch of libraries are left behind.  To fix the problem I deleted the following libraries from my site-packages directory:

```
gcloud
protobuf*
google
```

dev_appserver.py now can find the webapp module.

Here is the complete list of everything it installed if you want to delete it:

```
gcloud
gcloud-0.13.0.dist-info
google
googleapis_common_protos-1.1.0-py2.7-nspkg.pth
googleapis_common_protos-1.1.0-py2.7.egg-info
httplib2
httplib2-0.9.2-py2.7.egg-info
oauth2client
oauth2client-2.0.2-py2.7.egg-info
protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2-py2.7-nspkg.pth
protobuf-3.0.0b2.post2.dist-info
pyasn1
pyasn1-0.1.9.dist-info
pyasn1_modules
pyasn1_modules-0.0.8.dist-info
rsa
rsa-3.4.2.dist-info
```

Now someone better than me, needs to explain why this happened.

Finally the best way I found to install gcloud is using the instruction here:  https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27

Comment: You are an absolute legend. Thank you! I thought there was an easy fix, so started using my other Mac in the hope that there was a solution!